# D3_Position coordinates from csv

Tags: csv, d3.js, text, coordinates, axis

I have problem with rendering data from csv.
I need to render text elements according to their position by X and Y coordinates.

Firstly I tested to render data with this peace of code inline:

```
let dataset=[{x:100, y:100, text:"test1"},{x:120, y:120, text:"test2"},{x:140, y:140, text:"test3"}]
```

It was working Ok, so I decided to bind my csv-file with the same data in it and there is this error now in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

```js
let svg = d3.select(".snowflake")

let dataset;

// Load and process data
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dsibi/f5ca8cd7cd84eaa3c863c6ba247bf235/raw/9f934b89571e3b63621ecc03ae7f0bc805d5d5b3/labels_pos.csv", function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x = +d.x;
    d.y = +d.y;
  });
  dataset = data;
});

/* let dataset=[{x:100, y:100, text:"test1"},{x:120, y:120, text:"test2"},{x:140, y:140, text:"test3"}] */

d3.select("#labels")
  .append('svg')
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", d => d.x)
  .attr("y", d => d.y)
  .text(d => d.text)

d3.select('.ss')
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(250)
      .style("fill", "orange");
    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px")
      .text("Skating skills")
      .transition()
      .duration(250);
    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .classed("hidden", false);
    d3.select("#labels")
      .transition()
      .duration(250);
    d3.select("#labels")
      .classed("hidden", false);
    d3.select("#labels1")
      .style("left", "680px")
      .style("top", "60px")
      .text("Varied use of power, speed and acceleration")
      .transition()
      .duration(250);
    d3.select("#labels1")
      .classed("hidden", false);
  })
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    d3.select("#tooltip")
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px")
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(250)
      .style("fill", "steelblue");
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
    d3.select("#labels").classed("hidden", true);
    d3.select("#labels1").classed("hidden", true);
  });
```

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
a {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pcs_title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.path_block {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  /* background-color: #F5CCCC; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.snowflake {
  /* padding-left: 25px; */
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  fill: steelblue;
}


/* .snowflake:hover {
  fill: brown;
} */

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#tooltip.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#tooltip p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#labels {
  position: absolute;
}

#labels.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#labels1 {
  position: absolute;
}

#labels1.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="overlay">
    <!-- <h1 class="pcs_title">PCS</h1> -->
  </div>
</header>
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="labels" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="labels1" class="hidden"></div>
<div class="path_block">
  <svg class="snowflake" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 270">
            <g class="ss">
                    <path class="st1" d="M137.3,146c-0.3-1.5-0.6-3-0.9-4.6l-0.8-4.6c-0.5-3-1-6.1-1.4-9.1c0.1-6.1,0-12.2,0-18.3V18.3
                            c0.9-6.1,1.8-12.2,3-18.3c1.2,6.1,2.1,12.2,3,18.3v91.3c0,6.1,0,12.2,0,18.3c-0.4,3-0.9,6.1-1.4,9.1l-0.8,4.6
                            C137.9,143,137.6,144.5,137.3,146z"/>
                    <path class="st1" d="M137.3,55.1c-1.5,0.1-3,0-4.4-0.2c-0.7-0.8-1.5-1.5-2.3-2.3L126,48l-4.6-4.6l-2.3-2.3c-0.2-1.5-0.2-3-0.2-4.4
                            c1.5,0,3,0,4.4,0.2l2.3,2.3l4.6,4.6l4.6,4.6c0.8,0.8,1.5,1.6,2.3,2.3C137.3,52.1,137.4,53.6,137.3,55.1z"/>
                    <path class="st1" d="M137.3,105.1c-0.7-0.2-1.3-0.5-1.9-0.7l-1.9-0.8c-1.2-0.5-2.4-1.1-3.6-1.6c-1.7-1.8-3.5-3.5-5.2-5.3
                            l-10.5-10.5l-10.5-10.4l-5.2-5.2c-1.1-2.4-2.2-4.8-3.1-7.4c2.6,0.9,5,2,7.3,3.1l5.2,5.2l10.5,10.5L129,92.5
                            c1.8,1.7,3.5,3.5,5.3,5.2c0.6,1.2,1.1,2.4,1.6,3.6l0.8,1.8C136.9,103.8,137.1,104.4,137.3,105.1z"/>
                    <path class="st1" d="M137.3,85.1c0.1-0.5,0.2-1,0.3-1.5l0.4-1.5c0.3-1,0.5-1.9,0.8-2.8c1.3-1.2,2.4-2.4,3.7-3.6l7.3-7.3l7.3-7.3
                            l3.6-3.6c1.9-0.6,3.8-1.1,5.8-1.5c-0.4,1.9-0.9,3.9-1.5,5.8l-3.6,3.6l-7.3,7.3l-7.3,7.3c-1.2,1.2-2.4,2.4-3.6,3.7
                            c-0.9,0.3-1.8,0.6-2.8,0.8l-1.5,0.4C138.3,84.9,137.8,85,137.3,85.1z"/>
                    <path class="st1" d="M137.3,45.1c-0.1-1.5,0-3,0.2-4.5c0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,2.3-2.3l4.6-4.6l4.6-4.6l2.3-2.3c1.5-0.2,2.9-0.2,4.4-0.2
                            c0,1.5,0,3-0.2,4.4l-2.3,2.3l-4.6,4.6l-4.6,4.6c-0.8,0.8-1.6,1.5-2.3,2.3C140.3,45.1,138.8,45.2,137.3,45.1z"/>
            </g>
            <path class="st2" d="M137.3,146.2c-1.5-0.2-3.1-0.5-4.6-0.7l-4.6-0.8c-3-0.6-6-1.2-9-1.8c-5.7-2.1-11.4-4.2-17.2-6.3l-34.4-12.4
                    l-34.3-12.4l-17.2-6.2c-5.4-2.9-10.8-5.8-16.1-9c6.1,0.9,12.1,2.2,18.2,3.4l17.2,6.2l34.3,12.4l34.3,12.4
                    c5.7,2.1,11.4,4.2,17.2,6.2c2.7,1.4,5.4,2.9,8.1,4.4l4,2.3C134.6,144.6,136,145.4,137.3,146.2z"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M47.9,114.7c-0.4,1.4-1,2.8-1.7,4.1c-1,0.4-2,0.9-3,1.3l-5.9,2.8l-5.9,2.8l-3,1.4c-1.4-0.3-2.8-0.8-4.2-1.3
                    c0.5-1.4,1-2.8,1.7-4.1l3-1.4l5.9-2.8l5.9-2.8c1-0.5,2-0.9,2.9-1.4C45.1,113.6,46.5,114.1,47.9,114.7z"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M98,132.9c-0.4,0.6-0.9,1.1-1.3,1.6l-1.3,1.5c-0.9,1-1.8,1.9-2.8,2.8c-2.3,1-4.5,2.1-6.7,3.1l-13.4,6.3
                    l-13.4,6.3l-6.7,3.1c-2.7,0.3-5.3,0.4-8,0.4c1.7-2.1,3.6-4,5.4-5.9l6.7-3.1l13.4-6.3l13.4-6.3c2.2-1.1,4.5-2.1,6.7-3.2
                    c1.3-0.1,2.6-0.3,3.9-0.3l2-0.1C96.6,132.9,97.3,132.9,98,132.9z"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M73.5,122.2c-0.5-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.3-0.8l-1.2-0.8c-0.8-0.6-1.6-1.2-2.3-1.8c-0.7-1.6-1.4-3.1-2.2-4.7l-4.4-9.3
                    l-4.4-9.3l-2.2-4.7c0.1-2,0.2-4,0.5-5.9c1.7,1,3.4,2.2,4.9,3.4l2.1,4.7l4.4,9.3l4.4,9.3c0.7,1.6,1.4,3.1,2.2,4.6
                    c0,1-0.1,1.9-0.2,2.9l-0.2,1.5C73.7,121.2,73.6,121.7,73.5,122.2z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M137.3,146c-0.7,1.4-1.4,2.8-2.1,4.1l-2.2,4.1c-1.5,2.7-3,5.4-4.6,8c-3.8,4.8-7.5,9.6-11.3,14.3l-22.6,28.7
                    L71.9,234l-11.3,14.3c-4.5,4.2-8.9,8.4-13.6,12.5c2.8-5.5,5.9-10.9,8.9-16.2l11.3-14.4l22.6-28.7l22.6-28.7
                    c3.8-4.8,7.6-9.5,11.3-14.4c2.2-2.1,4.4-4.3,6.7-6.3l3.4-3.1C135,148.1,136.1,147,137.3,146z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M102.2,190.7c0.4,0.4,0.7,0.8,1,1.2l0.9,1.2c0.6,0.8,1.2,1.6,1.7,2.4c0.1,1.7,0.4,3.4,0.6,5.1l1.2,10.2
                    l1.2,10.2l0.6,5.1c-0.7,1.9-1.5,3.7-2.4,5.5c-1.3-1.5-2.5-3.1-3.6-4.8l-0.6-5.1l-1.2-10.2l-1.2-10.2c-0.2-1.7-0.4-3.4-0.6-5.1
                    c0.3-0.9,0.7-1.8,1.1-2.7l0.6-1.4C101.7,191.6,101.9,191.1,102.2,190.7z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M83.6,214.3c1.2,0.9,2.4,1.8,3.4,2.9c0.1,1.1,0.2,2.2,0.3,3.2l0.8,6.5l0.8,6.5l0.4,3.2
                    c-0.8,1.3-1.6,2.5-2.6,3.6c-1.2-0.9-2.3-1.8-3.4-2.9L83,234l-0.8-6.5l-0.8-6.5c-0.1-1.1-0.2-2.2-0.4-3.2
                    C81.8,216.6,82.7,215.4,83.6,214.3z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M93.4,201.8c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.7-1.2,1l-1.2,0.9c-0.8,0.6-1.6,1.1-2.4,1.7c-1.7,0.1-3.4,0.4-5.1,0.6l-10.2,1.2
                    l-10.2,1.2L58,209c-1.9-0.7-3.7-1.5-5.5-2.4c1.5-1.3,3.1-2.5,4.8-3.6l5.1-0.6l10.2-1.2l10.3-1.2c1.7-0.2,3.4-0.4,5.1-0.6
                    c0.9,0.3,1.8,0.7,2.7,1.1l1.4,0.6C92.5,201.3,93,201.5,93.4,201.8z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M74.9,225.4c-0.9,1.2-1.8,2.4-2.9,3.4c-1.1,0.1-2.2,0.2-3.2,0.4l-6.5,0.8l-6.5,0.8l-3.2,0.4
                    c-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.6-3.6-2.6c0.9-1.2,1.8-2.3,2.9-3.4l3.2-0.4l6.5-0.8l6.5-0.8c1.1-0.1,2.2-0.2,3.2-0.4
                    C72.6,223.5,73.8,224.4,74.9,225.4z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M112,178.2c-0.6,0.4-1.2,0.7-1.7,1.1l-1.7,1c-1.2,0.6-2.3,1.3-3.5,1.8c-2.4,0.2-4.9,0.6-7.3,0.9L83,184.7
                    l-14.7,1.8l-7.3,0.9c-2.6-0.6-5.2-1.3-7.7-2.1c2.3-1.4,4.6-2.7,7-3.9l7.3-0.9l14.7-1.8L97,177c2.4-0.3,4.9-0.6,7.3-0.9
                    c1.3,0.3,2.6,0.6,3.8,0.9l1.9,0.6C110.7,177.8,111.3,178,112,178.2z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M137.3,146c1.2,1,2.3,2.1,3.4,3.1l3.4,3.2c2.2,2.1,4.4,4.3,6.6,6.5c3.6,4.9,7.3,9.7,11,14.6l22,29.1l22,29.1
                    l11,14.6c2.9,5.4,5.9,10.8,8.6,16.4c-4.6-4.1-9-8.4-13.4-12.8l-11-14.6l-22-29.1l-22-29.1c-3.7-4.9-7.3-9.7-11-14.6
                    c-1.5-2.7-3-5.4-4.4-8.1l-2.1-4.1C138.7,148.8,138,147.4,137.3,146z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M191.9,214.2c1.1-1,2.4-1.8,3.6-2.6c1.1,0.2,2.1,0.3,3.2,0.5l6.4,0.9l6.4,0.9l3.2,0.4c1,1.1,2,2.2,2.8,3.4
                    c-1.2,0.9-2.4,1.8-3.6,2.5l-3.2-0.4l-6.4-0.9l-6.4-0.9c-1.1-0.1-2.1-0.3-3.2-0.4C193.6,216.6,192.7,215.5,191.9,214.2z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M162,178.7c0.7-0.2,1.3-0.4,1.9-0.6l1.9-0.5c1.3-0.3,2.6-0.6,3.9-0.9c2.4,0.4,4.9,0.7,7.3,1l14.6,2l14.6,2
                    l7.3,1c2.3,1.3,4.6,2.5,6.9,4c-2.5,0.8-5.1,1.4-7.7,1.9l-7.3-1l-14.6-2l-14.6-2.1c-2.4-0.3-4.9-0.7-7.3-1c-1.2-0.6-2.3-1.2-3.5-1.9
                    l-1.7-1C163.1,179.5,162.5,179.1,162,178.7z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M175.4,199.3c0.3,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.7,1.4l0.6,1.4c0.4,0.9,0.7,1.8,1,2.7c-0.3,1.7-0.5,3.4-0.7,5.1l-1.4,10.2
                    l-1.4,10.2l-0.7,5.1c-1.1,1.6-2.4,3.2-3.7,4.7c-0.9-1.8-1.6-3.6-2.3-5.5l0.7-5.1l1.4-10.2l1.5-10.2c0.2-1.7,0.5-3.4,0.7-5.1
                    c0.5-0.8,1.1-1.6,1.7-2.4l0.9-1.2C174.7,200.1,175,199.7,175.4,199.3z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M137.3,146.4c1.4-0.7,2.8-1.4,4.1-2.1l4.2-2c2.8-1.3,5.6-2.6,8.4-3.9c5.9-1.6,11.7-3.4,17.5-5.1l35-10.3
                    l35-10.3l17.5-5.1c6.1-0.8,12.2-1.7,18.4-2.3c-5.5,2.9-11.1,5.4-16.7,8l-17.5,5.1l-35,10.3l-35,10.3c-5.8,1.7-11.7,3.4-17.5,5.2
                    c-3,0.4-6.1,0.9-9.1,1.2l-4.6,0.5C140.4,146.1,138.9,146.3,137.3,146.4z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M186.6,131.9c0-0.7,0.1-1.4,0.1-2l0.2-2c0.1-1.3,0.3-2.6,0.6-3.9c1.2-2.1,2.4-4.3,3.6-6.5l7.1-13l7.1-13
                    l3.5-6.5c2-1.8,4.1-3.4,6.2-5c-0.2,2.7-0.5,5.3-0.9,7.9l-3.6,6.5l-7.1,13l-7.1,13c-1.2,2.2-2.4,4.3-3.5,6.5c-1,0.9-2,1.7-3,2.6
                    l-1.6,1.3C187.7,131.1,187.2,131.5,186.6,131.9z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M225.2,122c1.4-0.5,2.8-0.9,4.3-1.1c0.9,0.6,1.9,1,2.9,1.6l5.7,3.1l5.7,3.1l2.9,1.6c0.6,1.4,1.1,2.8,1.4,4.2
                    c-1.4,0.5-2.8,0.8-4.3,1.1l-2.9-1.6l-5.7-3.1l-5.7-3.1c-1-0.5-1.9-1.1-2.9-1.5C226,124.9,225.5,123.4,225.2,122z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M199.5,231c1,1.1,1.8,2.4,2.6,3.6c-0.2,1.1-0.3,2.1-0.5,3.2l-0.9,6.4l-0.9,6.4l-0.5,3.2c-1.1,1-2.2,2-3.4,2.8
                    c-0.9-1.2-1.8-2.4-2.5-3.6l0.4-3.2l0.9-6.4l0.9-6.4c0.1-1.1,0.3-2.1,0.4-3.2C197.1,232.8,198.3,231.8,199.5,231z"/>
        </svg>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

Thx

Answer (score 1):

`d3.csv` is an *asynchronous* function. It requests some external data source, but only executes the callback when it's done. In the meantime, it allows other code to be executed. In your case, you try to draw labels before the underlying data has been loaded.

In a diagram:

`d3 requests external data source` -> `you try to insert labels` -> `d3 sets dataset`.

In the following code, there is still a lot wrong with your setup, but the error has disappeared and you can see that `#labels` now has an `svg` child with three `text` nodes.

```js
let svg = d3.select(".snowflake")

let dataset;

// Load and process data
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dsibi/f5ca8cd7cd84eaa3c863c6ba247bf235/raw/9f934b89571e3b63621ecc03ae7f0bc805d5d5b3/labels_pos.csv", function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x = +d.x;
    d.y = +d.y;
  });
  dataset = data;

  d3.select("#labels")
    .append('svg')
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", d => d.x)
    .attr("y", d => d.y)
    .text(d => d.text)

  d3.select('.ss')
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .style("fill", "orange");
      d3.select("#tooltip")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px")
        .text("Skating skills")
        .transition()
        .duration(250);
      d3.select("#tooltip")
        .classed("hidden", false);
      d3.select("#labels")
        .transition()
        .duration(250);
      d3.select("#labels")
        .classed("hidden", false);
      d3.select("#labels1")
        .style("left", "680px")
        .style("top", "60px")
        .text("Varied use of power, speed and acceleration")
        .transition()
        .duration(250);
      d3.select("#labels1")
        .classed("hidden", false);
    })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      d3.select("#tooltip")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px")
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .style("fill", "steelblue");
      d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
      d3.select("#labels").classed("hidden", true);
      d3.select("#labels1").classed("hidden", true);
    });
});
```

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
a {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pcs_title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.path_block {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  /* background-color: #F5CCCC; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.snowflake {
  /* padding-left: 25px; */
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  fill: steelblue;
}


/* .snowflake:hover {
  fill: brown;
} */

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#tooltip.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#tooltip p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#labels {
  position: absolute;
}

#labels.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#labels1 {
  position: absolute;
}

#labels1.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="overlay">
    <!-- <h1 class="pcs_title">PCS</h1> -->
  </div>
</header>
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="labels" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="labels1" class="hidden"></div>
<div class="path_block">
  <svg class="snowflake" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 270">
            <g class="ss">
                    <path class="st1" d="M137.3,146c-0.3-1.5-0.6-3-0.9-4.6l-0.8-4.6c-0.5-3-1-6.1-1.4-9.1c0.1-6.1,0-12.2,0-18.3V18.3
                            c0.9-6.1,1.8-12.2,3-18.3c1.2,6.1,2.1,12.2,3,18.3v91.3c0,6.1,0,12.2,0,18.3c-0.4,3-0.9,6.1-1.4,9.1l-0.8,4.6
                            C137.9,143,137.6,144.5,137.3,146z"/>
                    <path class="st1" d="M137.3,55.1c-1.5,0.1-3,0-4.4-0.2c-0.7-0.8-1.5-1.5-2.3-2.3L126,48l-4.6-4.6l-2.3-2.3c-0.2-1.5-0.2-3-0.2-4.4
                            c1.5,0,3,0,4.4,0.2l2.3,2.3l4.6,4.6l4.6,4.6c0.8,0.8,1.5,1.6,2.3,2.3C137.3,52.1,137.4,53.6,137.3,55.1z"/>
                    <path class="st1" d="M137.3,105.1c-0.7-0.2-1.3-0.5-1.9-0.7l-1.9-0.8c-1.2-0.5-2.4-1.1-3.6-1.6c-1.7-1.8-3.5-3.5-5.2-5.3
                            l-10.5-10.5l-10.5-10.4l-5.2-5.2c-1.1-2.4-2.2-4.8-3.1-7.4c2.6,0.9,5,2,7.3,3.1l5.2,5.2l10.5,10.5L129,92.5
                            c1.8,1.7,3.5,3.5,5.3,5.2c0.6,1.2,1.1,2.4,1.6,3.6l0.8,1.8C136.9,103.8,137.1,104.4,137.3,105.1z"/>
                    <path class="st1" d="M137.3,85.1c0.1-0.5,0.2-1,0.3-1.5l0.4-1.5c0.3-1,0.5-1.9,0.8-2.8c1.3-1.2,2.4-2.4,3.7-3.6l7.3-7.3l7.3-7.3
                            l3.6-3.6c1.9-0.6,3.8-1.1,5.8-1.5c-0.4,1.9-0.9,3.9-1.5,5.8l-3.6,3.6l-7.3,7.3l-7.3,7.3c-1.2,1.2-2.4,2.4-3.6,3.7
                            c-0.9,0.3-1.8,0.6-2.8,0.8l-1.5,0.4C138.3,84.9,137.8,85,137.3,85.1z"/>
                    <path class="st1" d="M137.3,45.1c-0.1-1.5,0-3,0.2-4.5c0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,2.3-2.3l4.6-4.6l4.6-4.6l2.3-2.3c1.5-0.2,2.9-0.2,4.4-0.2
                            c0,1.5,0,3-0.2,4.4l-2.3,2.3l-4.6,4.6l-4.6,4.6c-0.8,0.8-1.6,1.5-2.3,2.3C140.3,45.1,138.8,45.2,137.3,45.1z"/>
            </g>
            <path class="st2" d="M137.3,146.2c-1.5-0.2-3.1-0.5-4.6-0.7l-4.6-0.8c-3-0.6-6-1.2-9-1.8c-5.7-2.1-11.4-4.2-17.2-6.3l-34.4-12.4
                    l-34.3-12.4l-17.2-6.2c-5.4-2.9-10.8-5.8-16.1-9c6.1,0.9,12.1,2.2,18.2,3.4l17.2,6.2l34.3,12.4l34.3,12.4
                    c5.7,2.1,11.4,4.2,17.2,6.2c2.7,1.4,5.4,2.9,8.1,4.4l4,2.3C134.6,144.6,136,145.4,137.3,146.2z"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M47.9,114.7c-0.4,1.4-1,2.8-1.7,4.1c-1,0.4-2,0.9-3,1.3l-5.9,2.8l-5.9,2.8l-3,1.4c-1.4-0.3-2.8-0.8-4.2-1.3
                    c0.5-1.4,1-2.8,1.7-4.1l3-1.4l5.9-2.8l5.9-2.8c1-0.5,2-0.9,2.9-1.4C45.1,113.6,46.5,114.1,47.9,114.7z"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M98,132.9c-0.4,0.6-0.9,1.1-1.3,1.6l-1.3,1.5c-0.9,1-1.8,1.9-2.8,2.8c-2.3,1-4.5,2.1-6.7,3.1l-13.4,6.3
                    l-13.4,6.3l-6.7,3.1c-2.7,0.3-5.3,0.4-8,0.4c1.7-2.1,3.6-4,5.4-5.9l6.7-3.1l13.4-6.3l13.4-6.3c2.2-1.1,4.5-2.1,6.7-3.2
                    c1.3-0.1,2.6-0.3,3.9-0.3l2-0.1C96.6,132.9,97.3,132.9,98,132.9z"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M73.5,122.2c-0.5-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.3-0.8l-1.2-0.8c-0.8-0.6-1.6-1.2-2.3-1.8c-0.7-1.6-1.4-3.1-2.2-4.7l-4.4-9.3
                    l-4.4-9.3l-2.2-4.7c0.1-2,0.2-4,0.5-5.9c1.7,1,3.4,2.2,4.9,3.4l2.1,4.7l4.4,9.3l4.4,9.3c0.7,1.6,1.4,3.1,2.2,4.6
                    c0,1-0.1,1.9-0.2,2.9l-0.2,1.5C73.7,121.2,73.6,121.7,73.5,122.2z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M137.3,146c-0.7,1.4-1.4,2.8-2.1,4.1l-2.2,4.1c-1.5,2.7-3,5.4-4.6,8c-3.8,4.8-7.5,9.6-11.3,14.3l-22.6,28.7
                    L71.9,234l-11.3,14.3c-4.5,4.2-8.9,8.4-13.6,12.5c2.8-5.5,5.9-10.9,8.9-16.2l11.3-14.4l22.6-28.7l22.6-28.7
                    c3.8-4.8,7.6-9.5,11.3-14.4c2.2-2.1,4.4-4.3,6.7-6.3l3.4-3.1C135,148.1,136.1,147,137.3,146z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M102.2,190.7c0.4,0.4,0.7,0.8,1,1.2l0.9,1.2c0.6,0.8,1.2,1.6,1.7,2.4c0.1,1.7,0.4,3.4,0.6,5.1l1.2,10.2
                    l1.2,10.2l0.6,5.1c-0.7,1.9-1.5,3.7-2.4,5.5c-1.3-1.5-2.5-3.1-3.6-4.8l-0.6-5.1l-1.2-10.2l-1.2-10.2c-0.2-1.7-0.4-3.4-0.6-5.1
                    c0.3-0.9,0.7-1.8,1.1-2.7l0.6-1.4C101.7,191.6,101.9,191.1,102.2,190.7z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M83.6,214.3c1.2,0.9,2.4,1.8,3.4,2.9c0.1,1.1,0.2,2.2,0.3,3.2l0.8,6.5l0.8,6.5l0.4,3.2
                    c-0.8,1.3-1.6,2.5-2.6,3.6c-1.2-0.9-2.3-1.8-3.4-2.9L83,234l-0.8-6.5l-0.8-6.5c-0.1-1.1-0.2-2.2-0.4-3.2
                    C81.8,216.6,82.7,215.4,83.6,214.3z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M93.4,201.8c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.7-1.2,1l-1.2,0.9c-0.8,0.6-1.6,1.1-2.4,1.7c-1.7,0.1-3.4,0.4-5.1,0.6l-10.2,1.2
                    l-10.2,1.2L58,209c-1.9-0.7-3.7-1.5-5.5-2.4c1.5-1.3,3.1-2.5,4.8-3.6l5.1-0.6l10.2-1.2l10.3-1.2c1.7-0.2,3.4-0.4,5.1-0.6
                    c0.9,0.3,1.8,0.7,2.7,1.1l1.4,0.6C92.5,201.3,93,201.5,93.4,201.8z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M74.9,225.4c-0.9,1.2-1.8,2.4-2.9,3.4c-1.1,0.1-2.2,0.2-3.2,0.4l-6.5,0.8l-6.5,0.8l-3.2,0.4
                    c-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.6-3.6-2.6c0.9-1.2,1.8-2.3,2.9-3.4l3.2-0.4l6.5-0.8l6.5-0.8c1.1-0.1,2.2-0.2,3.2-0.4
                    C72.6,223.5,73.8,224.4,74.9,225.4z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M112,178.2c-0.6,0.4-1.2,0.7-1.7,1.1l-1.7,1c-1.2,0.6-2.3,1.3-3.5,1.8c-2.4,0.2-4.9,0.6-7.3,0.9L83,184.7
                    l-14.7,1.8l-7.3,0.9c-2.6-0.6-5.2-1.3-7.7-2.1c2.3-1.4,4.6-2.7,7-3.9l7.3-0.9l14.7-1.8L97,177c2.4-0.3,4.9-0.6,7.3-0.9
                    c1.3,0.3,2.6,0.6,3.8,0.9l1.9,0.6C110.7,177.8,111.3,178,112,178.2z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M137.3,146c1.2,1,2.3,2.1,3.4,3.1l3.4,3.2c2.2,2.1,4.4,4.3,6.6,6.5c3.6,4.9,7.3,9.7,11,14.6l22,29.1l22,29.1
                    l11,14.6c2.9,5.4,5.9,10.8,8.6,16.4c-4.6-4.1-9-8.4-13.4-12.8l-11-14.6l-22-29.1l-22-29.1c-3.7-4.9-7.3-9.7-11-14.6
                    c-1.5-2.7-3-5.4-4.4-8.1l-2.1-4.1C138.7,148.8,138,147.4,137.3,146z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M191.9,214.2c1.1-1,2.4-1.8,3.6-2.6c1.1,0.2,2.1,0.3,3.2,0.5l6.4,0.9l6.4,0.9l3.2,0.4c1,1.1,2,2.2,2.8,3.4
                    c-1.2,0.9-2.4,1.8-3.6,2.5l-3.2-0.4l-6.4-0.9l-6.4-0.9c-1.1-0.1-2.1-0.3-3.2-0.4C193.6,216.6,192.7,215.5,191.9,214.2z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M162,178.7c0.7-0.2,1.3-0.4,1.9-0.6l1.9-0.5c1.3-0.3,2.6-0.6,3.9-0.9c2.4,0.4,4.9,0.7,7.3,1l14.6,2l14.6,2
                    l7.3,1c2.3,1.3,4.6,2.5,6.9,4c-2.5,0.8-5.1,1.4-7.7,1.9l-7.3-1l-14.6-2l-14.6-2.1c-2.4-0.3-4.9-0.7-7.3-1c-1.2-0.6-2.3-1.2-3.5-1.9
                    l-1.7-1C163.1,179.5,162.5,179.1,162,178.7z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M175.4,199.3c0.3,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.7,1.4l0.6,1.4c0.4,0.9,0.7,1.8,1,2.7c-0.3,1.7-0.5,3.4-0.7,5.1l-1.4,10.2
                    l-1.4,10.2l-0.7,5.1c-1.1,1.6-2.4,3.2-3.7,4.7c-0.9-1.8-1.6-3.6-2.3-5.5l0.7-5.1l1.4-10.2l1.5-10.2c0.2-1.7,0.5-3.4,0.7-5.1
                    c0.5-0.8,1.1-1.6,1.7-2.4l0.9-1.2C174.7,200.1,175,199.7,175.4,199.3z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M137.3,146.4c1.4-0.7,2.8-1.4,4.1-2.1l4.2-2c2.8-1.3,5.6-2.6,8.4-3.9c5.9-1.6,11.7-3.4,17.5-5.1l35-10.3
                    l35-10.3l17.5-5.1c6.1-0.8,12.2-1.7,18.4-2.3c-5.5,2.9-11.1,5.4-16.7,8l-17.5,5.1l-35,10.3l-35,10.3c-5.8,1.7-11.7,3.4-17.5,5.2
                    c-3,0.4-6.1,0.9-9.1,1.2l-4.6,0.5C140.4,146.1,138.9,146.3,137.3,146.4z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M186.6,131.9c0-0.7,0.1-1.4,0.1-2l0.2-2c0.1-1.3,0.3-2.6,0.6-3.9c1.2-2.1,2.4-4.3,3.6-6.5l7.1-13l7.1-13
                    l3.5-6.5c2-1.8,4.1-3.4,6.2-5c-0.2,2.7-0.5,5.3-0.9,7.9l-3.6,6.5l-7.1,13l-7.1,13c-1.2,2.2-2.4,4.3-3.5,6.5c-1,0.9-2,1.7-3,2.6
                    l-1.6,1.3C187.7,131.1,187.2,131.5,186.6,131.9z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M225.2,122c1.4-0.5,2.8-0.9,4.3-1.1c0.9,0.6,1.9,1,2.9,1.6l5.7,3.1l5.7,3.1l2.9,1.6c0.6,1.4,1.1,2.8,1.4,4.2
                    c-1.4,0.5-2.8,0.8-4.3,1.1l-2.9-1.6l-5.7-3.1l-5.7-3.1c-1-0.5-1.9-1.1-2.9-1.5C226,124.9,225.5,123.4,225.2,122z"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M199.5,231c1,1.1,1.8,2.4,2.6,3.6c-0.2,1.1-0.3,2.1-0.5,3.2l-0.9,6.4l-0.9,6.4l-0.5,3.2c-1.1,1-2.2,2-3.4,2.8
                    c-0.9-1.2-1.8-2.4-2.5-3.6l0.4-3.2l0.9-6.4l0.9-6.4c0.1-1.1,0.3-2.1,0.4-3.2C197.1,232.8,198.3,231.8,199.5,231z"/>
        </svg>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thx, for your comment and corrections. But as far as I understood in this case it is better to use `async/await` here. What do you think?

Comment: It's not that simple, `d3.csv` only started to support `.then` in v5, so you'd have to do a major upgrade and rewrite. Other than that, async/await works only if you have a transpiler like Babel and it's equivalent to `d3.csv.then`, which is what I'd have recommended if you were using d3 v5 anyway

Comment: Hey, sorry, I looked a little bit closer and see that there is still no any connection with my csv-file. I need to do this secifically. Do you have an idea how?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "no any connection with my csv file"? 2. What do you mean by "I need to do this secifically"?

Comment: One answer to both questions: I need to load X and Y positions from csv-file as coordinates for label's text

Comment: What do you have now and how is that not working?